# Simulating a click on a nested link within a nested a div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem simulating a click on a nested link within a nested div using jQuery. Can anyone help with the following? How would I simulate a click on the link with `id=video2` in the code below?

```
<div id=tS2 class=outer>
 <div class=middle>
   <div class=inner>
    <a href="#" id=video1 class=trigger><img src="imgs/thumbs/thumb_01.jpg"></a>
    <a href="#" id=video2  class=trigger><img src="imgs/thumbs/thumb_02.jpg" ></a>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all, your html is incorrect. `id="video1" class="trigger"`

Comment: What do you mean by simulating a click? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: `$("#video2").trigger("click");` if you have a click function attached using jQuery.

If you don't have a jQuery click event attached, and you just want to simulate a click and get the default behaviour. Use: `document.getElementById("video2").click();`, but with your current setup, doing this would just send you to the same page again, as you only have a `#` in your `href` attribute.

Even though things will work without them in this case, you should add double quotes around you HTML attributes to make your HTML valid.

Comment: Missing a `#` in the selector: `$("#video2")`

Comment: jQuery's `.trigger()` will simulate events regardless of how they were attached. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9ZU68/5/).

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot - My "using jQuery" is only there because the post has a jQuery tag attached, and OP is not showing any JavaScript/jQuery which is attaching events in the question. It is not meaning to imply that the function has to be attached using jQuery or else it will not work. :)